# Conditionally execute a subquery with MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a view which describes some statistics of another table, e.g.:

```
create table people (
  playerid INT not null auto_increment,
  name VARCHAR(70),
  primarykey (playerid)
);

create view personinfo_oranges (playerid, number_of_oranges) as
  select playerid, count(orangeid) from oranges
  ...
;
```

Unfortunately, there's loads of data in the tables that `person_info` looks at (e.g. oranges) and the view is very slow to load. This is apparently a [known issues with views](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/). So I created another table that stores the data for some of the people (e.g. when they become allergic to oranges):

```
create table person_summary (
  playerid INT not null,
  number_of_oranges INT,
  foreign key (playerid) references players(playerid)
);
```

Ideally I would like to create a view that searches `person_summary`, and, if not found, looks in `personinfo_oranges`. I could do this logic in my Model layer, but how can I do it in MySQL?

Comment: maybe it is a known issue of some sort, but we can not see your actual `view` code and schema showing such things as indexes, column types

Comment: Let's see the "very slow" load code.